# How i Add my App in default dialer options

Tags: android, android-intent, android-dialer

I want to add my `app` in `default options`. When some one `making a call` he will show my app as options `like skype,viber etc`.

i have used following line of code but not worked.

```
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Refer the following link: [Possible duplicate of] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765118/programmatically-change-launcher-activity

Comment: @NishatLakhani the question you posted it's not related, Muhammad plz check this questiotn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029183/android-dialer-application